# Outputing a double array, unexpected output numbers in C

Tags: arrays, c, printf, double

I tried printing an array in C, but the Output doesn't match the numbers in the array. Im just starting to learn C so this is probably a really nooby mistake but I would appreciate a solution.

```
int main() {
double arr[] = {1,0.2,
                0.3,0.4,0.5,
                0.6,0.7};
for(int i =0; i<7;i++){
    printf("%d ",arr[i]);
}return 0;}
```

Output: `0 -1717986918 858993459 -1717986918 0 858993459 1717986918`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `%d` format specifier (as well as `%i`) is for printing an `int` in decimal, not a `double`.

You want to use `%f` instead.

```
printf("%f ",arr[i]);
```

Output:

```
1.000000 0.200000 0.300000 0.400000 0.500000 0.600000 0.700000
```

Comment: oh... I thought %i is for int and %d for doubles... so thanks for the quick awnser!

Comment: @base I think %d is for decimals.

Comment: @base https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf